# Prove that $\boldsymbol{v}^T\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}\boldsymbol{v}\boldsymbol{z}^T\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{z} \ge (\boldsymbol{v}^T\boldsymbol{z})^2$

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, quadratic-forms, positive-definite

I'm facing the following problem:

Prove that

$$
\boldsymbol{v}^\top\boldsymbol{A}^{-1}\boldsymbol{v}\boldsymbol{z}^\top\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{z} \ge (\boldsymbol{v}^\top\boldsymbol{z})^2
$$

where $\boldsymbol{v},\boldsymbol{z} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are unit vector ($||\boldsymbol{v}||=||\boldsymbol{z}||=1$) and $\boldsymbol{v}^\top\boldsymbol{z}>0$, $\boldsymbol{A}\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is symmetric and positive definite.

I am reasonably sure that the assertion is true because I tested it numerically with a lot of random numbers. But I don't find a way to prove this. There exist any property that I can exploit?

If I am able to prove it in the restricted case $n=3$ and/or $\boldsymbol{A}$ diagonal, it is still fine for me. Obviously, it is nicer to have a more generic proof.

Comment: If you diagonalize $A$ by orthogonal matrix, we find that we can assume $A$ is diagonal. Now, just expand everything then i think the inequality becomes cauchy-schwarz.

Comment: The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality seems the key.

The Cauchy–Schwarz inequality states:
$$
(x^Ty)^2 \le x^T x y^T y
$$
now take
$x = A^{-1/2}v$ and $y=A^{1/2}z$, where $A^{1/2} : A = A^{1/2}A^{1/2}$
this take us to the initial inequality.

Do you think that it is correct proof? I'm missing something?

Comment: @Marco. I think you are assuming that $A^{\pm \frac12}$ exists and is symmetric. T|his may well be true but probably needs to be shown.

Answer (score 1):

The identity that should be helpful here is the identity

$$\|I\|\leq \|A\|\cdot \|A^{-1}\|$$